# ERB & PHP together. *.php.erb?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, erb

I have to work with another team that is developing in php, when I'm developinging ruby. Normally this isn't a problem, as they usually hand the source off to me to finish. There are multiple reasons why I prefer to deploy rails applications, and the PHP is a compromise at this point. I now not only have to deal with their php, but they've signed a contract to update the site.

I asked them if they knew if they were going to be doing content updates or code or both, and they aren't sure at this point.

What I would like to do is use .php.erb files to allow them to use their php, even though the code doesn't always follow best practices, it gets the job done. That way I'm only responsible for the parts I am and not maintaining anything I won't be paid for when they change the structure of the site.

Is it possible to allow them to use  <%= render :partial => "form" %> or other ERB tags in their php or some other solution that allows them to edit their side of things and incorporate mine?

Is Erubis an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `require 'php'` in your .erb template using [this gem](http://php.rubyforge.org/).